# SQL: условие выборки года между началом и концом интервала

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста составить  MySQL выражение для выборки модели автомобиля.

В базе есть поля: `mdoel_id`, `start`, `end`. Где `start` и  `end` - дата начала и окончания производства.

Если пользователь введет год(одно число, например, 1998), то нужно выбрать все записи находящиеся между `start` и `end`.

Comment: Какой тип имеют поля start и end?

Comment: @cheops int - число

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  1998 BETWEEN start AND `end`
```

Это условие эквивалентно

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  1998 >= start AND 1998 <= `end`
```

Если вам не нужно включать границы года (`start` и `end`), достаточно заменить операторы >= и <= на > и <.